# (Matlab) Get rid of input data in probability object

Tags: matlab, probability, distribution

I have fitted a probability distribution to my dataset using Matlabs [fitdist](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitdist.html) function:

```
load hospital
x = hospital.Weight;
pd = fitdist(x,'Normal');
```

In `pd.InputData` the whole data is stored. Of course if this data is large, the probability object pd gets very big. Unfortunately, `pd.InputData` is read only, so I cannot delete it.

Is there a way to get rid of it? Of course I could just create a new probability distribution object with makedist and the according parameters but the problem is that I'm fitting all possible distributions, so I would have to make a mapping for all distributions.